# Pygame Zero: Different background images for different level possible?

Tags: python, multi-level, pgzero

I am creating a small game with python and pygame zero. In the game i like to use different background images for different level. So, if the user reaches level 2 a new background image should appear. Is this possible. I tried this, but i always get the error message: "pygame.error: Couldn't open images\background2.png". The path is 100% correct. Here is my full code:

```
from random import randint
import pygame

WIDTH   = 800
HEIGHT  = 800

apple = Actor("apple")
apple.pos = randint(0, 800), randint(-800, 0)

pear = Actor("pear")
pear.pos = randint(0, 800), randint(-800, 0)

plum = Actor("plum")
plum.pos = randint(0, 800), randint(-800, 0)

donut = Actor("donut")
donut.pos = randint(0, 800), randint(-800, 0)

ice = Actor("ice")
ice.pos = randint(0, 800), randint(-800, 0)

chips = Actor("chips")
chips.pos = randint(0, 800), randint(-800, 0)

burger = Actor("burger")
burger.pos = randint(0, 800), randint(-800, 0)

happysmiley = Actor("happysmiley")
happysmiley.pos = 300, 750

start = Actor("start")
start.pos = 700,750

quitgame = Actor("quit")
quitgame.pos = 600, 750

creditsinfo = Actor("credits")
creditsinfo.pos = 485, 750

back = Actor("back")
back.pos = 600, 100

nextlevel = Actor("nextlevel")
nextlevel.pos = 700, 750

gameover = False
score = 0
gamemode = 1
gamestart = 0
level = 0

background = pygame.image.load("images\\background.png")
background2 = pygame.image.load("images\\background2.png")

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("music\\funmusic.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

def draw():
    global gamemode
    screen.clear()
    if gamemode == 0 and score >= 100:
        endoflevel1()
    else:
        drawgame()

    if gamemode == 3 and score >= 150:
        endoflevel2()


def drawgame():
    global gamemode

    if gamemode == 1:
        screen.clear()
        screen.blit("background",(0,0))
        apple.draw()
        pear.draw()
        plum.draw()
        donut.draw()
        ice.draw()
        chips.draw()
        quitgame.draw()
        happysmiley.draw()
        start.draw()
        creditsinfo.draw()
        screen.draw.text("Punkte: " + str(score), (700, 5), color = "black")

    elif gamemode == 0:
        screen.clear()
        screen.blit("background",(0,0))
        apple.draw()
        pear.draw()
        plum.draw()
        donut.draw()
        ice.draw()
        chips.draw()
        happysmiley.draw()
        screen.draw.text("Punkte: " + str(score), (700, 5), color = "black")

    elif gamemode == 2:
        screen.clear()
        screen.fill("orange")
        back.draw()
        screen.draw.text("Credits", topleft=(350,10), fontsize=40)
        pygame.display.flip()

    elif gamemode == 3:
        screen.clear()
        screen.blit("background2",(0,0))
        apple.draw()
        pear.draw()
        plum.draw()
        donut.draw()
        ice.draw()
        chips.draw()
        burger.draw()
        happysmiley.draw()
        screen.draw.text("Punkte: " + str(score), (700, 5), color = "black")

def update():
    global score, gamestart

    if gamestart == 1:

        if score >= 100:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            return

        if apple.y < 800:
            apple.y = apple.y + 4
        else:
            apple.x = randint(0, 800)
            apple.y = randint(-800, 0)

        if pear.y < 800:
            pear.y = pear.y + 4
        else:
            pear.x = randint(0, 800)
            pear.y = randint(-800, 0)

        if plum.y < 800:
            plum.y = plum.y + 4
        else:
            plum.x = randint(0, 800)
            plum.y = randint(-800, 0)

        if donut.y < 800:
            donut.y = donut.y + 4
        else:
            donut.x = randint(0, 800)
            donut.y = randint(-800, 0)

        if ice.y < 800:
            ice.y = ice.y + 4
        else:
            ice.x = randint(0, 800)
            ice.y = randint(-800, 0)

        if chips.y < 800:
            chips.y = chips.y + 4
        else:
            chips.x = randint(0, 800)
            chips.y = randint(-800, 0)

        if keyboard.left:
            happysmiley.x = happysmiley.x - 5
        elif keyboard.right:
            happysmiley.x = happysmiley.x + 5

        if happysmiley.collidepoint (apple.x, apple.y):
            score = score + 2
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds\\bonus.wav")
            effect.play()
        if happysmiley.collidepoint (pear.x, pear.y):
            score = score + 1
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds\\bonus.wav")
            effect.play()
        if happysmiley.collidepoint (plum.x, plum.y):
            score = score + 1
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds\\bonus.wav")
            effect.play()
        if happysmiley.collidepoint (donut.x, donut.y):
            score = score - 1
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds\\no.wav")
            effect.play()
        if happysmiley.collidepoint (ice.x, ice.y):
            score = score - 1
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds\\no.wav")
            effect.play()
        if happysmiley.collidepoint (chips.x, chips.y):
            score = score - 1
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds\\no.wav")
            effect.play()

    if level == 2:
        if burger.y < 800:
            burger.y = burger.y + 4
        else:
            burger.x = randint(0, 800)
            burger.y = randint(-800, 0)


        if happysmiley.collidepoint (burger.x, burger.y):
            score = score - 1
            effect = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds\\no.wav")
            effect.play()

def on_mouse_down(pos): # wurde Maustaste gedrückt?
    global score, gamestart, gamemode

    if start.collidepoint(pos):
        gamestart = 1
        gamemode = 0
    if quitgame.collidepoint(pos):
        exit()
    if creditsinfo.collidepoint(pos):
        gamemode = 2
    if  back.collidepoint(pos):
        gamemode = 1

def endoflevel1():
    global score, gamemode, gamestart, level
    screen.clear()
    screen.fill("green")
    screen.draw.text("Congratulations! You have successfully completed the 1st level!", topleft=(100,350), fontsize=30, color = "black")
    nextlevel.draw()  
    gamestart = 0
    pygame.display.flip()
    running = True
    while (running):
        for event in pygame.event.get():  
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if  nextlevel.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    score = 0
                    gamemode = 3
                    gamestart = 1
                    level = 2
                    running = False

def endoflevel2():
    global score, gamemode, gamestart, level
    screen.clear()
    screen.fill("orange")
    screen.draw.text("Congratulations! You have successfully completed the 2nd level!", topleft=(100,350), fontsize=30, color = "black")
    nextlevel.draw()  
    gamestart = 0
    pygame.display.flip()
```

The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Programmierung\Mu\pkgs\pgzero\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Programmierung\Mu\pkgs\pgzero\runner.py", line 92, in main
    exec(code, mod.__dict__)
  File "ninjatest2.py", line 53, in <module>
    background2 = pygame.image.load("images\\background2.png")
pygame.error: Couldn't open images\background2.png
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
```

Comment: Does the code work if you only load the background2 image? (ie, only have one background for both levels, but have it be background2)?

Comment: yes, code works if i only load background2 image. Yes i like to have 2 different backgrounds for both levels

Comment: hmm interesting. Could you add the full stacktrace to your question?

Comment: you mean full error message when i want to start program/game?

Comment: yes, it typically says what line it failed on, and what the full error is.  It is helpful to see because it will typically include what line the pygame code errored out on.

Comment: ok, i included it.

Comment: hmm, is it related to those `libpng` warnings?

Comment: no, i always get these warnings and game is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203690/discussion-between-user1558604-and-siclaro). Hopefully someone else will be able to help